# dynamically added links that returns false not working after adding audio

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-audio

I have dynamically added links for Chapters that when clicked, displays the description of the chapter (gets the data from localStorage)

```
$('#chapterList #chapter_ul a').live('click', function(){   
var chID = $(this).attr("id");
$('#chapterDesc p').fadeOut(300).remove();
$('<p></p>').html(localStorage.getItem(chID)).appendTo('#chapterDesc');
$('#chapterDesc p').hide();
$('#chapterDesc p').fadeIn(500);            

return false;

});
```

the code above works, then I added code for an audio to play when the link is clicked just before the return false line,

```
if($('#eventAudio').length>0){ //check if there is an existing #eventAudio in DOM
$('#eventAudio')[0].remove(); //removes it
}
else{
    playAudio('audio/','bytes/',soundBytes,0,0); //if no existing, calls the playAudio function
}
if($('#eventAudio').length>0){//checks if there is a new #eventAudio
$('#eventAudio')[0].play();//plays it
}
```

playAudio function

```
    function playAudio(thisLoc,thisSubF,thisArray,thisMusic,looping){
      $('<audio></audio>').attr('id','eventAudio').attr('src',thisLoc+thisSubF+thisArray[thisMusic]).appendTo('#mainContent');
   if(looping==1){
    $('#eventAudio').attr('onended','play()')
   }
}
```

again, the code actually works, but just once. The next time I click on the links, they just go to the pages that they are linked to. the live('click') function doesn't work anymore. I've been stuck on this code for two hours now. Anybody, please help? Thanks in advance!

*EDIT:* I am testing this on Safari 5.1

Answer (score 0):

To remove the element from the DOM use

```
$('#eventAudio').remove();
```

When you use `$('#eventAudio')[0]` it returns the DOM element (*and not the jQuery object*) which does not have a `.remove()` method.

So, that line causes the script to fail and the `return false` is never executed, and the link is followed..

Comment: wow. how did i miss that? i spent 2 hours for 3 characters that I forgot to remove. Thanks!